# HTTP GET-Request in Kotlin/Android Studio

Tags: android, http, kotlin, post, get

I am facing a problem with coding my first Android-App.

I want to build the login-system of the app around my existing webserver/webinterface.

I am using the Fuel-Library, and as far as I can tell, the GET Requests are working fine.
The problem is the response. When I print it out, everything is see is some information about the request itself, but the printed echo from PHP isn't showing up anywhere.

Response printed out:

```
I/System.out: <-- 200 https://...hidden :)
I/System.out: Response : OK
    Length : -1
    Body : test
    Headers : (11)
    Connection : Keep-Alive
    Date : Mon, 30 Mar 2020 18:06:39 GMT
    X-Android-Selected-Protocol : http/1.1
    Server : Apache
    X-Powered-By : PHP/7.3.5, PleskLin
    Content-Type : text/html; charset=UTF-8
    X-Android-Received-Millis : 1585591597000
    Vary : Accept-Encoding
    X-Android-Response-Source : NETWORK 200
    X-Android-Sent-Millis : 1585591596960
    Keep-Alive : timeout=5, max=100
```

The same is happening with POST Requests.

Here is my Kotlin-Code:

```
val url = "https://myserver.com/testlogin.php?username=".plus(username.toString()).plus("&password=").plus(password.toString())
    url.httpGet().responseString{
        request, response, result ->
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

And the PHP Code on the Webserver:

```
<?php $username = $_GET["username"]; $password = $_GET["password"]; echo $username; ?>
```

I am searching for more than 7 hours now. send help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  url.httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {
                val ex = result.getException()
                println(ex)
            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                val data = result.get()
                println(data)
            }
        }
    }
```

[Official documentation](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem:

```
val data = result.get() println(data)
```

prints the response string of the php file.